# My phone display turns off automatically even though the feature is set to never

Tags: screen, 7.0-nougat

I own a Asus ZenFone 3 Max running a Nougat. From the past few days, my phone screen turns off automatically if left unattended for at least 10 seconds approximately. I have my "sleep" feature under "display" in settings set to never. But this still happens. What may be the problem?

*I did get my screen broke like from a month ago. But I hadn't faced such an issue from last few days. So maybe I don't think if I could actually relate that to this.

[image]

Edit:

My phone got an app called Mobile manager which have something called the power master.
[image]

Again the power master opens as:

[image]

I then tried checking out the option called Battery mode:

[image]

and customized goes as:

[image]

Comment: Does setting it to 30, help?

Comment: @ABochur No. I just tried it yesterday. There weren't any positive results actually.

Comment: Is there any battery saver or something?

Comment: @ABochur No power saver actually. There is an app called the mobile manager which have an option called power master. I have add screenshots of the these and some other ones in the edit ( of the question. )

Comment: Feel that it is due to the power master app.If that is a pre-installed app, disable it from settings and see if it helps. If you installed it yourself , uninstall that. Since that app is not available (for me) on Play Store, it may be pre installed and some setting in it over rides the choice you made

Comment: @beeshyams I tried it now as you said. Still no use. The screen turns off after 10 secs.

Comment: Probably related to hardware changes you made since your question implies that this problem is a recent one